# Is it possible to make PDFRenderer in Android Studio find and render a PDF that is stored in a cloud database (i.e. Firebase)?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, pdfrenderer

I am new to Android Studio and am using it to develop a client application for a non profit organization. The client app is heavily dependent on the ability to display various PDF documents. I would like to know the following:

Is it possible to use PDFRenderer in Android Studio to find and render a PDF that is stored in a cloud database (i.e. Firebase)? The goal is to avoid storing the PDF files locally, as I expect the number of PDFs to be in the hundreds.

I am aware of an alternate solution of using a webview to point to a specific URL such as a Google Doc, but that approach seems volatile and I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Any help, suggestions, and/or feedback would be greatly appreciated. I thank you for your assistance in advance.

-D. Moore

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with Firebase Storage. That service allows you to upload your files to the cloud and the Firebase's SDK provides functions to get the download links too.

On these docs you'll find everything you need to know to do what you're asking for.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files